# "FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux: Unknown error -2make: *** [Makefile:1162: vmlinux] Error 255", while compiling kernel-5.9.1

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, make

I am trying to compile kernel-5.9.1 using `make`

I got the following error while **make**-ing

> FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux: Unknown error -2make: ***
> [Makefile:1162: vmlinux] Error 255

I am using Ubuntu-20.4 on Oracle Virtual-Box 6.0.24

The only nice source I could find online is this ***[conversation](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/10/20/752)***. From this, it appears, the problem is in one of the packages named **[pahole](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pahole#)**.

I remember having encountered another error during this make only asking me to install pahole version v1.17, which I did successfully.

**How to fix the following issue?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today, for me the issue was that pahole ran out of memory (peak memory usage of pahole was around 2.5GB).

You can verify this by checking `sudo dmesg | grep pahole`.

If that is indeed your problem, try increasing the memory of your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Just quick FYI: Current linux build needs at least 10GB of RAM!

I was just trying to build kernel 6.5 and noticed the process was being killed after both SWAP+RAM was getting full. I started with 4.0 of RAM on my VM, then increased until it passed.

I noticed the linux building process needing about 10GiB of RAM to finish building without throwing that error. This is crazy on how much RAM it needs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm usually annoyed by automated replies, but this I think they may have a point here. Memory consumption is incredibly dependent on [selected modules](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-objtool-allyesconfig-RAM), optimizations, LTO and other gcc flags. In particular, if `pahole` is involved you are probably looking into the entire problem disappearing if all debuginfo was stripped.