# FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux : No such file or directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, make

While trying to build kernel (4.15) with support Ftrace and debug info, I am getting the following error:

```
       FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux: No such file or directory
       Makefile:1160: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
```

This is what I am trying:

```
       $ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_FTRACE
       $ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO
       $ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5
       $ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL
       $ ./scripts/config -e CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
       $ ./scripts/config -d CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED
       $ yes "" | make oldconfig
       $ make -j$(nproc) Image dtbs modules
```

This issue seems to be different from this one:

["FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux: Unknown error -2make: *** [Makefile:1162: vmlinux] Error 255", while compiling kernel-5.9.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616392/failed-load-btf-from-vmlinux-unknown-error-2make-makefile1162-vmlinu)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are trying to install kernel 4.15 in 2022, but besides the point you should not run `yes "" | make oldconfig`. This will select yes for new questions. What you probably want it is to `make olddefconfig` which will select the default for new questions (which isn't necessarily yes). This could be part of your problem.

You should also make sure dwarves is installed.

Comment: This doesn't help. I got same problem while trying to bisect between 6.0 and 6.1rc1, the former fails with the same error. Didn't run `oldconfig`, and for a dozen of new *(or probably older since apparently they are not present at 6.1.rc1)* options pressed enter which has been always defaulting to `N`. That didn't stop me from getting the same problem though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the actual reason for the error may be a dozen lines above the error about `load BTF from vmlinux: No such file or directory`.

In my case that was a warning *(yes, it's a warning because it does not interrupt build)*:

```
           […]
           BTF     .btf.vmlinux.bin.o
         btf_encoder__encode: btf__dedup failed!
         Failed to encode BTF
           […]
```

…and this problem was a regression on an early development stage, which I worked around by disabling `CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT`.